# how to understand the action of PHP interpreter ?

Tags: php

I save the file as hallo.php.

```
<html>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<body>
<form action="hallo.php" method="POST">
    Username <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    Password <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Login!"><br />
</form>
<?php
    if($_POST['submitbutt']) {
    echo "username: " . $_POST['username'] . "<br />";
    echo "password: " . $_POST['password'] . "<br />";
    }
    else {
         }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When i input 127.0.0.1\hallo.php, i got the output1.

[image]

When i input `hallo` in usename ,`hallo` in password and click longin! , got the output2,

[image]

Why i can not get the output3?

[image]

Comment: Because your `<form>` should be in the `else` to achieve that.

Comment: Please, learn about cropping images :-) Windows Vista and newer includes the snipping tool, which is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<form>` isn't output conditionally. It's output UNconditionally - every time you load that script, the form will appear. You want something more like this:

```
if ($_POST['submitbutt']) {
   ... output username/password
} else {
   ... output form
}
```

If a form was submitted, the form won't be printed. if *no* form was submitted, the form will be printed.